# calling a function defined in assembly from swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I know in swift it is possible to interop with c using the `@_silgen_name` attr on a function in a swift module. Is there a way to do this with a symbol defined in an assembly file? I would like to make syscalls using Swift. This is why I'm asking.

Comment: A compiled object file has no idea whether it was compiled from C, or assembled from assembly language.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths how does the compiler know where the symbol thats in the asm file is when its compiling the swift module?

Comment: In exactly the same way that it knows where the symbol is with a C source file - it looks it up in the symbol table of the object file.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths but I haven't told the compiler to link it. is there a special flag I need to pass in or something?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125338/how-can-i-use-an-a-static-library-in-swift) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the bridge header.h file and put the prototype of the function in that file.

For example your assembly code:

```
.globl _add // make it global so that others can find this symbol
....
_add: // int add(int a, int b)
  movl %esi, %eax
  addl %edi, %eax
  ret
```

Then in bridging header.h file

```
int add(int a, int b);
```

OR

define this at the top of the swift module

```
@_silgen_name("add") func add(a: Int32, b: Int32) -> Int32
```

Then in swift you can use it:

```
let a = add(1, 2);
```

Comment: what flags do I pass into the swiftc compiler for it to link the assembly file?

Comment: Just put in the same XCode project.

Comment: Then try this `swiftc -import-objc-header add.h app.swift add.o -o app` where add.h contain the header, add.o is compiled assembly code.

Comment: Thanks for this, do you know who to compile assembly because I can't seem to find any flags in clang to do that. I tried `clang -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel add.s`

Comment: This is what I tried `g++ -c main.s`. Can you try `llvm-g++ -c main.s`?

Comment: Thanks! works now and I also figured out that you can skip the bridge header by declaring `@_silgen_name("add") func add(x: Int32, y:Int32) -> Int32` in the swift module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123110/discussion-between-jack-sexton-and-daniel-tran).

Comment: `lea (%esi, %edi), %eax` would be more efficient.  Or for 64-bit code: `lea (%rsi, %rdi), %eax`, because the address-size prefix has no effect if you're truncating the result to the default 32-bit operand-size.