# How are function parameters passed when calling symbols in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I saw this sample code in a previous question I asked. I was confused by how the paramaters of `int add(int a, int b)` were automatically in esi and edi? Is this a default calling convention? Where can I find more of this information.

```
.globl _add // make it global so that others can find this symbol
....
_add: // int add(int a, int b)
  movl %esi, %eax
  addl %edi, %eax
  ret
```

Comment: What does "a default" mean? What good is a default if you have twenty different defaults?

Comment: _"Where can I find more of this information"_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: @Michael thanks that helps, couldn't find the answer for parameters auto loaded into esi and edi though

Comment: Could you show us the passing code?

Comment: @Downvoter http://stackoverflow.com/a/39421006/4107796 this is where I got the code from.

Comment: _"couldn't find the answer for parameters auto loaded into esi and edi though"_ Note that `esi` and `edi` are the low halves of `rsi` and `rdi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calling convention of the System V AMD64 ABI is followed on Solaris, Linux, FreeBSD, OS X,[16] and is the de facto standard among Unix and Unix-like operating systems. The first six integer or pointer arguments are passed in registers RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX (R10 in the Linux kernel interface[17]:124), R8, and R9, while XMM0, XMM1, XMM2, XMM3, XMM4, XMM5, XMM6 and XMM7 are used for certain floating point arguments.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: More specific links to detailed ABI docs in [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  There's also a less detailed summary of [x86 calling conventions in SO docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/3261/calling-conventions)