# Why is the Xcode command line nasm assembly issuing error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix

Tags: xcode, assembly, nasm

My goal is to use Xcode (10.2-beta) to write C and Assembly for MacOS (14.1); I want to use the NASM instead of the default GNU compiler, the GAS syntax is quite horrible.

***BTW, although I configured Xcode to use NASM, as you will see below, I suspect it is not using it!***

I've built my project using the GNU compiler. It runs fine.

```
// main.c
# include <stdio.h>

int myOperation(int a, int b);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    // insert logic here
    int x = 10;
    int y = 12;
    int z = myOperation(x, y);
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d\n", x, y, z);
    return 0;
}

//  assembly.s
.text
.globl _myOperation

_myOperation:
    add %esi, %edi
    mov %edi, %eax
    ret
```

I installed the XCode command line tools and changed the build rules to compile NASM files. The C file is the same:

```
//  assembly.s
.text
.globl _myOperation

_myOperation:
    add edi, esi
    mov eax, edi
    ret
```

Building rules
[image: Xcode build rule]

I get the following errors:

```
/Users/rodrigomattososilveira/projects/asm/NASM Tutorial/Tutorial_01AA/Tutorial_01AA/assembly.s:12:5: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
    add edi, esi
    ^
/Users/rodrigomattososilveira/projects/asm/NASM Tutorial/Tutorial_01AA/Tutorial_01AA/assembly.s:13:5: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
    mov eax, edi
    ^
Command CompileC failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Some of the links I've checked out:

- [X86 Assembly/GAS Syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax)
- [Compiling NASM Assembly with Xcode in a C/C++ Project](https://metricpanda.com/compiling-nasm-with-xcode-in-a-cpp-project)
- [Xcode and NASM coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556241/xcode-and-nasm-coding)
- [Writing 64 Bit Assembly on Mac OS X](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2014/12/02/writing-64-bit-assembly-on-mac-os-x/)
- The top links suggested at the time I created this issue

Comment: A file with suffix `.s` is treated as an assembly file in AT&T syntax using the system's own assembler.  Use the suffix `.asm` (I think) for a file to be processed with NASM.

Comment: The error message isn't from NASM. NASM wouldn't find anything objectionable in `add edi, esi`.

Comment: Replacing the .s suffix with .asm did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hint at [this Reddit posting](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/7io68r/how_can_i_program_in_x8664_assembly_language_on/):

> Looks like gas can take Intel syntax, but you have to specify it with the **.intel_syntax** flag.

Now, this code compiles:

```
.intel_syntax // THIS DID THE TRICK

.text
.global _myOperation

_myOperation:
    add edi, esi
    mov eax, edi
    ret
```

Comment: That's still not NASM syntax; note the `.text` directive, and `.global` instead of `global`.  More importantly, `mov eax, foobar` is a load from `[foobar]` in GAS's `.intel-syntax`, unlike NASM where it's a `mov reg, imm32`.  GNU `.intel_syntax` is MASM-like.  See  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info

Comment: Correct, I jumped the gun. Somehow Xcode seems to have abandoned NASM, so I'll have to abandon attempting to write NASM using Xcode

Comment: I'd assume you can configure Xcode with custom build rules to manually tell it how to run NASM, even if you're right that it doesn't come with a built-in NASM mode anymore.  But actually, avoiding NASM for OS X would probably be a good idea; there have been multiple serious bugs in NASM's `macho64` support over the years.  [Successive sys\_write syscalls not working as expected, NASM bug on OS X?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49224997) [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](//stackoverflow.com/q/47300844)

Comment: @PeterCodes, wise suggestion regarding not using NASM. Is there anything other than GAS you would recommend

Comment: YASM is nasm-compatible.  I don't know how good its OS X support is, and it's not well maintained (still lacking AVX512 support), but it's otherwise very good on Linux.